# How does initialize() work in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I've got a part of code, which contains all objects of controllers which I've been using in my program. The `topButtonsController` is the only one injected from FXML file (fx:include), the others are created by myself.

I recon that `initialize()` method is invoked after the constructor of MainController in created, so assuming that all the methods from the `initialize()` methods should have do their job firstly.

```
public class MainController {
   @FXML
   private TopButtonsController topButtonsController;

   private AddNewOrderController addNewOrderController = new AddNewOrderController();

   private OrdersController ordersController = new OrdersController();

   @FXML
   private BorderPane borderPane;

   @FXML
   public void initialize() {
       topButtonsController.setMainController(this);
       addNewOrderController.setMainController(this);
       ordersController.setMainController(this);
       System.out.println("Finished injection");    
   }
}
```

Here I've got a class of controller for another FXML file. After pressing the button the `acceptButtonClicked` method should invoked, but unfortunately the `mainController` is Null! Why it is so if I've already set him to a value in MainController `initialize` method, that should have been hit first.

```
public class AddNewOrderController {

   private MainController mainController;

   @FXML
   private TextField nameOfPizzaTextField;

   private ArrayList<Order> arrayList = new ArrayList<Order>();

   private ObservableList<Order> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(arrayList);

   @FXML
   private Button acceptButton;
   @FXML
   void acceptButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) {
       if(mainController == null) {
           System.out.println("MainController is null!!"); //it is printed, why?
       }

       Order order = new Order(nameOfPizzaTextField.getText());
       arrayList.add(order);
       observableList.add(order);
       System.out.println("Dodano "+nameOfPizzaTextField.getText()+"do listy");
       System.out.println(observableList);
       mainController.getOrdersController().getListView().setItems(mainController.getAddNewOrderController().getObservableList()); // here occurs error

   @FXML
   public void initialize() {
   }

   public void setMainController(MainController mainController) {
       this.mainController= mainController;
   }
}
```

Comment: The `acceptButtonClicked` method looks like a handler method that is invoked on the controller for the FXML file. You are calling `setMainController` on an instance of `AddNewOrderController` that you create "by hand": that is not the controller. You need to call `setMainController` on the actual controller that is instantiated when the corresponding FXML file is loaded.

Comment: Okey I understand that i miss the idea of which controller i get. So how can I achive getting right controller. Is it by the FXMLLoader class? FXMLLoader loader = FXMLLoader(..); loader.getController() ?

Comment: You have to get the controller when you load (and display) the FXML file. (Call `getController()` *after* calling `load()`).

Comment: I still dont get it. If I do so I will let know other controller that there are others controller (because I need to create such field in other files) E.g I load all my fxml files in TopMenuButtonsController so I need to create there 3 additional fields with instance of controllers and than how to pass it to another files? I want only mainController to know that more controllers exist. Do you have any ready app or example which emphasise problem ?

Comment: I don't really understand how you are trying to organize the application. If your `TopMenuButtonsController` is loading the FXML files, it needs to do any necessary initialization on the corresponding controllers. The FXML file and controller work as a fairly tightly-coupled pair: if the `TopMenuButtonsController` is loading the FXML files, then it is really already implicitly creating the controllers too.

Comment: I usually avoid controllers communicating with each other entirely, and prefer a MVC approach, so you share a single model instance with all the controllers. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx

Comment: Or perhaps, since `TopMenuButtonsController` has a reference to the main controller, you should move the code for loading and displaying the other FMXL files to the main controller (which might be a more natural place for it), and then just invoke methods on the main controller to load those FXML files from the `TopMenuController`. Again, there's not really enough information in your question to understand what you are trying to do.